# React/React-Router: componentWillUnmount not called when routing to new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React app that uses React-Router, I have a Home component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Home extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, true);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 // scroll event handling
}

render () {
 return (<div>
            // markup
            <Link to="/secondPage"></Link>
        </div>);
 }
}

export default Home;
```

However, when I click on the Link, navigating from "/" to "/secondPage", it routes to the new page but hasn't removed the event listener from the Home component.

According to the [React-Router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/800991cd2044293718fccd3763b9d91c2f811296/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md), it seems that componentWillUnmount should be called.

Why is componentWillUnmount not called?

Comment: Did you check by placing a console log there?

Comment: Yep, I did check and it's not calling componentWillUnmount.

Comment: Hey, I am facing, the same problem. I've posted the issue in the link below. If you have solved this, I'd like to hear how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771610/reactjs-executing-code-when-route-changes?noredirect=1#comment116289734_65771610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding / removing an event listener we must keep the formats same in order to get expected result. In your code, you used this one to add event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, true);
```

But for removing the listener, you used this one:

```
window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
```

I suggest you try with this one for removing event listener.

```
window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, true);
```

Also, you have used semicolon after the opening braces.

```
componentDidMount() {;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to bind handleScroll? I like using fat arrow notation for that.
`handleScroll = (e) => { ... }`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that -- this.handleScroll is bound correctly.